# Can't install 12.04 inside Windows 7 using WUBI

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

I've tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows 7 so many times, as the installation is done, a window pops up:

```
An error occurred:
NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'
For more information please see the log file
```

Here is my log:
http://pastebin.com/knwT92E6

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/989991) - remove the CD and run Wubi standalone again. Also take a look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1641044)

Comment: Thank you.I tried putting wubi in the same folder with the Iso file,I also let wubi to download a new Iso,both lead to this pop-up: Error executing command >>command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe ...  Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/DvSQCbSZ